# Mahalanobis Distance and Linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normal-distribution

I am not very up to date on my linear algebra skills and I am having some trouble understanding an explanation from the book Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning, (Bishop).

It says , consider Mahalnobis distance, $\Delta^{2}=(x-\mu)^{T}\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)$

Where $\Sigma$ is a real symmetric matrix ( the variance covariance matrix).

"Because $\Sigma$ is real and symmetric, its eigenvalues will be real and its eigenvectors can be chosen to form an orthonormal set, so that ..."

$u_{i}^{T}u_{j}=I_{ij}$

and $\Sigma$ can be  written as

$$\Sigma= \sum_{i=1}^{D} \lambda_{i} u_{i}u_{i}^{T}$$

and $$\Sigma^{-1}=\sum_{i=1}^{D} \frac{1}{\lambda_{i}}u_{i}u_{i}^{T}$$

so $$\Delta^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{D} \frac{y_{i}^{2}}{\lambda_{i}}$$

where $$y_{i}=u_{i}^{T}(x-\mu)$$

I am just looking to understand these steps better. I don't understand how it is achieved. I understand the basics such as real spectral theorem tells us we have a diagonlization with an orthogonal matrix, but I do not understand how they use that to calculate $\Sigma$ , $\Sigma^{-1}$ and the choice of $y_{i}$. I am more interested in the actual interpretation. The geometric and how it it can be used.

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the Mahalanobis distance is actually defined as $\sqrt{\Delta^2} = \sqrt{(x-\mu)^\intercal \Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)}$.  Think in analogy to the "Euclidean" distance (the "usual" distance between two points), which is the *square root* of the sum of squares.

The main idea behind using eigenvectors is that you're choosing a basis for $\Bbb{R}^D$ that is "better suited" for the application of the matrix $\Sigma$ and its inverse.  The better basis is the basis consisting of (orthonormalized) eigenvectors of $\Sigma$.

Why is this a "better" basis, you ask?  Well, several reasons:

1. If $u_j$ is an eigenvector of $\Sigma$, we have $\Sigma u_j = \lambda_j u_j$.  In other words, applying the linear transformation is really easy for eigenvectors: we just scale them.
2. Because $\Sigma$ is positive semi-definite, we can make an *orthonormal* basis of eigenvectors.  Orthonormal bases are particularly nice because expressing an arbitrary vector in that basis is easy.  Say $y\in \Bbb{R}^D$.  Then, saying $\{u_j\}$ is an orthonormal basis is equivalent to saying that

$$
y = \sum_{j=1}^D (y^\intercal u_j) u_j = \sum_{j=1}^Du_j(u_j^\intercal y)
$$  Why is this identity helpful? If we apply $\Sigma$ and use the fact that $\Sigma u_j = \lambda_j u_j$, we immediately see why:

$$
\Sigma y = \sum_{j=1}^D\Sigma u_j (u_j^\intercal y)= \sum_{j=1}^D\lambda_j u_j (u_j^\intercal y) \tag{1}
$$  Another way to write this is simply

$$
\Sigma = \sum_{j=1}^D\lambda_j u_ju_j^\intercal \tag{2}
$$  (Apply both sides to $y$ to see why (1) and (2) are the same).  Note that (2) is completely equivalent to the "spectral decomposition" of $\Sigma$, which is usually written as

$$
\Sigma = U\Lambda U^\intercal \tag{3}
$$ where $U$ is the matrix of eigenvectors, which satisfies $U^\intercal U = I$, and $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues.

3. Not only is it easy to apply $\Sigma$ if we change basis to $\{u_j\}$, but it's also easy to apply the inverse.  Suppose we want to solve the equation

$$
\Sigma x = y
$$ Using the matrix expression (3), we can write this as

$$
U\Lambda U^\intercal x = y
$$   Now, we know that $U^\intercal U = I$, so we can apply $U^\intercal$ to both sides of the equation:

$$
U^\intercal U\Lambda U^\intercal x = U^\intercal y
$$ and so

$$
\Lambda U^\intercal x = U^\intercal y \tag{4}
$$  what this equation says, by the way, is that the *coefficients* of $x$ in the basis $\{u_j\}$ are related to the *coefficients* of $y$ in the basis $\{u_j\}$ by a diagonal matrix $\Lambda$.   Assuming that $\lambda_j>0$, we can solve the equation (4) easily too:

$$
U^\intercal x = \Lambda^{-1}U^\intercal y
$$  The inverse of a diagonal matrix is just the diagonal matrix with $1/\lambda_j$, by the way.  Finally, we can apply $U$ to both sides to get

$$
x = U\Lambda^{-1}U^\intercal y
$$  Another way to write this is

$$
x = \Sigma^{-1}y = \sum_{j=1}^D \frac{1}{\lambda_j} u_j u_j^\intercal y \tag{5}
$$  Or, equivalently,

$$
\Sigma^{-1} = \sum_{j=1}^D \frac{1}{\lambda_j}u_ju_j^\intercal
$$   Finally, how do we use these expressions to get the Mahalanobis distance in the eigenvector basis?   Well, suppose first that we want to compute $\Sigma^{-1}(x - \mu)$.   We can simply apply expression (5):

$$
\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu) = \sum_{j=1}^D\frac{1}{\lambda_j}u_ju_j^\intercal (x-\mu) =\sum_{j=1}^D\frac{u_j^\intercal (x-\mu) }{\lambda_j}u_j
$$  Now, to compute $\Delta^2$, we multiply both sides by $(x-\mu)^\intercal$, use linearity of sums and symmetry of the dot product:

$$
\Delta^2 = (x-\mu)^\intercal \sum_{j=1}^D\frac{u_j^\intercal (x-\mu) }{\lambda_j}u_j = \sum_{j=1}^D\frac{u_j^\intercal (x-\mu) }{\lambda_j}(x-\mu)^\intercal u_j = \sum_{j=1}^D \frac{y_j^2}{\lambda_j}
$$where $y_j = (x-\mu)^\intercal u_j$.

Geometrically, what does $y_j = (x-\mu)^\intercal u_j$ represent?   Well, think of $x$ as a datapoint; subtracting the mean simply makes the origin $\mu$ instead of $0$.  Then, $(x-\mu)^\intercal u_j$ is the component of the (re-centered) datapoint in the direction of the eigenvector $u_j$.  This eigenvector is usually called a *principal component* in the statistics literature; so, $(x-\mu)^\intercal u_j$ is the "amount" of the (re-centered) datapoint in the direction of the $j$th principal component.

So why is the Mahalanobis distance a "distance"? Is there a geometric interpretation of this?  Indeed - we're switching our basis to the principal component (eigenvector) basis, then simply computing a *weighted* euclidean distance between our data point $x$ and the mean $\mu$.  The weights are the (inverse) eigenvalues $\lambda_j$.  Why choose these weights?   Well, smaller eigenvalues of $\Sigma$ correspond to weaker correlations; we want to normalize correlations before computing the distance.

Another good way to think about it is that we're performing a *whitening* transformation before computing distances: if we define

$$
z = \Sigma^{-1/2}(x-\mu) 
$$  Then, we have

$$
\Delta^2 = z^\intercal z
$$  It's called a whitening transformation because it converts random vectors to "white noise", i.e. vectors with mean $0$ and covariance $I_{D\times D}$.  This is just like the "Z score" transformation you learn in Stat 101:

$$
Z = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}
$$

Hope that helps.  Usually I would draw pictures but I don't have the time.  There should be some YouTube videos out there on Mahalanobis and PCA that can help.